# if statement inside a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi I tried creating an if statement inside a mysql query but I dont know where I went wrong.
What I tried to do is to deduct 8 from a column value if that column value is more than 8 hours. Here' what I have done so far

```
$sql="UPDATE timekeeping SET actualend = timestamp(NOW()), logoutdate = date(NOW()),
totalhours = ((SELECT sum(time_to_sec(timediff(actualend,actualstart))/3600) AS
'totalhours') - 1.50), 
excesstime = (if (totalhours > 8) 
   {
excesstime = (totalhours - 8);
   }
)  WHERE actualend IS NULL and fullname = '$loginuser[fullname]'";
```

So if I show a table like the one below

time in, timeout, totalhours, excesstime respetively

9:00:00  |    18:00:00  |   9   |   1   <------this should be the answer(1)

Sorry abut this but I'm so new in mysql as well as in php.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're attempting to use a flow control statement in your query, where you actually need a flow control *function*. Use the `if()` function instead.

Try this:

```
$sql="UPDATE timekeeping SET actualend = timestamp(NOW()), logoutdate = date(NOW()),
totalhours = ((SELECT sum(time_to_sec(timediff(actualend,actualstart))/3600) AS
'totalhours') - 1.50), 
excesstime = if(totalhours > 8,totalhours-8,0)
  WHERE actualend IS NULL and fullname = '$loginuser[fullname]'";
```

The flow control statements are used in stored procedures, triggers, etc. and aren't valid in single-line queries.

MySQL reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: @user3465736 if this answer was the solution (which it seems to be), be sure to accept this as the answer in order to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: It seems that I'm getting an error with it.`if(totalhours > 8,totalhours-8,0)` It still computes even though total hours is less than 8.

Comment: @user3465736 I can't see immediately why you'd be having a problem with this. Are you sure it's not being affected by something else? Post your schema and some data you're having trouble with and I'll take a look

Comment: @MikeW I'll edit my post so that you can see the database along with some data. Thank you

Comment: I've rolled your edit back since what you're now asking is a different question and removing the old content invalidates the original question and answer. But, you're getting the right values. You're converting from `datetime` values to `float`. `6.75 hours` _is_ `6 hours 45 minutes`.  If you want hours and minutes use `timediff(endtime, starttime`) and store the result in a `TIME` column.  Format as appropriate when you SELECT it. See [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f082d/1/0).